# How to create a setup for vb.net application?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I developed an Accounting System. Now I'm trying to create a setup file. And my client wants it to be used in multi-user mode.

I developed it using Visual Studio 2010, SQL Server 2008 for the database and Crystal Report for reporting.

What I'm doing is, I install sql server 2008 and sql management and copy the database to its directory and attach it.

While I used Advanced Installer to create a setup file for my system and installing it by clicking the output file setup.

But my problem is normal users didn't know how to do this things. So I want to create a ONE setup file which will install SQL Server 2008, Crystal Report, My Accounting System and update TCP Dynamic Ports of SQL Server Instance to 1433.

I already created a batch file which will install SQL Server 2008 and create database but I don't know how to make it available in local network.

Hope someone can help me, Just leave a comment if I did not give enough details to my question. Thanks.

Note: I want a setup file with progress bar and details of what is being install.

Comment: You can get close doing this, we write an installer application to do it. There are so many variables though. Permissions of the user installing, both on the client and the target machine for the server. Different os's , backup and restore strategies, coping with re-installs, moving the server, windows updates, firewalls, a/v suites. For instance you say you are messing with 1433, what if they already have a sql server installed on that port?. Ctrix, windows terminal server. Remote servers. Hiding to nothing mate.

Comment: Hello @TonyHopkinson thanks for your comment, Did you already done something like this? Any tips on how to make it in other ways or in your ways?

Comment: Write an app the will check the machine to see if your software can be installed. Same sort of thing ms do for sql server. You need certain things to be true on the client and the server. Report where they aren't suggest remedial measures. Let the people who know the target network, get it to pass. Then your install is does the tool pass, yes go, go, go.

Comment: PS That wasn't where we started, and we regretted it, a lot.

Comment: Here's one failure we had one firewall a/v suite put up an allow through dialog when we requested something in the installer. Our stay on top splash screen was on top of it. The allow through stays on x seconds and then assumes no if no response. We assumed yes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advanced Installer can do all of those things, you need to set them as prerequisites, and provide an installation source for them.  This link is for express. Providing progress during the SQL install is a little clumsy, it can be a lengthy install, and you can either show "Installing SQL" for a long time and use quiet install, or let the SQL install dialogs show.

[Install sql express](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/howto-install-sql-server-express.html)

Crystal Reports is a bit of a pain (in more ways than one), but there is an MSI that can be included in the AI project; make sure you get the right version and be aware of 32/64 bit differences. I use CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_4.msi and CRRuntime_64bit_13_0.msi

I haven't done updating ports of SQL instance, I just use the browser service, but you can inject vbscript into the install process and do just about anything.

Proper licensing must be adhered to for deployment of all the runtimes.

Comment: Hi @SqlACID thanks for you answer, with regards to browser service, I haven't used it. but can I use it to activate a multi-user mode? What about creating a database and execute a script I done this using a batch file. Can I run this in Advanced Installer?

Comment: Yes, that's what the browser service is for, you connect to a machine saying "I'm looking for instance XYZ", the browser server says "You find that on port 1433"; it's much better to use it than force port numbers on people. And the Browser service has to be set to Automatic; I think the Express install sets it to Manual.

Comment: Thanks for that information @SqlACID I will check some article on how to use it. And I hope I can apply it to my setup file. Thanks again.